# Trying to DateFormatting Optional String

Tags: swift, option-type

Currently i'm getting all the invoice data from my Rails API.

```
func get(path: String) {
    let url = NSURL(string: path)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if(error != nil) {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        do {
            let results = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves)
            self.delegate.didReceiveAPIResults(results as! NSArray)
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    })

    task!.resume()
}
```

Then i pass the array with results to my delegate in the InvoicesController:

```
func didReceiveAPIResults(results: NSArray) {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        for invoice in results {
            // Create an individual item
            Invoice.createInManagedObjectContext(self.managedObjectContext,
                invoiceStatus: String(invoice["status"]),
                invoicePrice: NSDecimalNumber(string: String(invoice["price"])),
                invoiceDate: dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-06-22T17:57:21.313Z")!,
                invoiceDueDate: String(invoice["invoice_date"])

            )
        }
    })
}
```

But i can't convert the invoice["invoice_date"] optional to an valid date, currently it returns an nil.

I've tried some things in the Playground and there it works with an Optional value:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

var dateString:String? = "2015-06-22T17:57:21.313Z"

dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString!)
```

By using:

```
invoiceDate: dateFormatter.dateFromString(String(invoice["invoice_date"]))!
```

I'm getting this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)
```

Someone some suggestions? I'm using swift 2 on iOS 9 platform.

Comment: Have you tried `println(String(invoice["invoice_date"]))` to see what it looks like? It may be that your string doesn't match your dateFormatter's `dateFormat`

Comment: try like this  dateFormatter.dateFromString(invoice["invoice_date"]!)! or if let invoiceDate = invoice["invoice_date"] { ... }

Comment: I suspect @trevor is right, but when dealing with RFC 3339/ISO 8601 dates, it's prudent to set `locale` to `en_US_POSIX` per [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Comment: I added the NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") to the date formatter but it doesn't solve the problem. It works when i don't use the object but manually pass the string: 2015-06-22T17:57:21.313Z. So i think it's something with the Optional. I also tried: `dateFormatter.dateFromString(invoice["invoice_date"]!)!` but that doesn't work too.

Comment: This code: `print(String(invoice["invoice_date"]))`
`print(dateFormatter.dateFromString(String(invoice["invoice_date"]!)))`

returns:
`Optional(2015-06-22T17:57:21.313Z)
nil
Optional(2015-07-07T00:00:00.000Z)
nil`

Comment: Try `print(String(invoice["invoice_date"])!)` Essentially you want to make sure you're not getting "Optional(...)" but rather just some string value

Comment: @trevorj, i think the problem is there. But with your snippet, i've get this compiler error: Could not find an overload for subscript that accepts the supplied arguments

Comment: How about `print(invoice["invoice_date"] as! String)`?

Comment: Thanks!! That fixes my problem :) But i think it's not such nice code to first define the `invoice["invoice_date"] as! String` and then pass it to the date formatter. See my gist: https://gist.github.com/MathijsK93/5915e8ffe6de8be162c0

Comment: If all objects in `results` are dictionaries with String as key and String as value, you can avoid casting inside the loop by casting the array itself: `for invoice in results as! [[String:String]]`

Comment: Thanks that's much cleaner! You saved my day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was answered in the comments, but thought I'd put it here:

There was a problem in the cast, and using

```
invoice["invoice_date"] as! String
```

solved it.